# Retrieve Titles From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a simple Multi Selection Field:

```
<MultiSelectText
    multiple={true}
    options={this.props.fields}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    name="fields"
    label="fields"
    items={this.props.fields}
    sorting="sorting"
/>
```

And the array I retrieve sort of looks like this:

```
[{name: 'Animals', label_parent: '', sorting: 1}, {name: 'Duck', label_parent: 'Animals', sorting: 2}, {name: 'Dog', label_parent: 'Animals', sorting: 3}, {name: 'Cat', label_parent: 'Animals', sorting: 4}, {name: 'Vehicles', label_parent: '', sorting: 5}, {name: 'Bike', label_parent: 'Vehicles', sorting: 6}, {name: 'Car', label_parent: 'Vehicles', sorting: 7}, {name: 'Motorcycle', label_parent: 'Vehicles', sorting: 8}];
```

Currently my Multi Input looks like this:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSFql.png)

But I need it to look like this:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CIqs.png)

I want to set a label everywhere where "label parent" is empty... for all other fields I have a label_parent set to either "cat" or "vehicles", and they need to be displayed as selection fields in these label "categories". Is there a way to display mutliple MultiInputTexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution myself.

Basically you want to filter out all the label by checking the string and create a new array

```
 let animals = this.props.fields.filter(function (a) {
               return a.label === 'Animals';
 });
```

And then just create a each MultiInput where you set

```
options={animals}
```

I suppose you could also do a loop here?